# Raspbian ~/.xinitrc File Missing

Tags: raspbian

I booted up my Raspberry Pi for the first time using the full NOOBS installer... I am using the Raspberry Pi 2 (it has two USBs, one Ethernet, one HDMI, and one SD Card port)... I use it over SSH and VNC on my local network... I was thinking of installing a new Desktop Environment because I found the old one rather boring, and I was used to XFCE with Ubuntu, not Raspberry Pi default Desktop Environment with Raspbian Wheezy =), so I went and was looking at the Raspbian MATE Desktop Environment (a fork off of Gnome) and thought it would be nice, so I proceeded to add `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/mate wheezy main` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I then ran `sudo apt-get update`, and then the two components of MATE with this: `sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment`. The instructions told me to add `exec mate-session` to my `~/.xinitrc` followed by running the command `startx`. It went completely fine up until I had to edit my `~/.xinitrc`, which happened to be non-existent... this is the result of running `ls -a`:

```
.
..
.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bashrc
.cache
.config
.dbus
Desktop
.dmrc
.dosbox
Downloads
.fontconfig
.galculator
Games
.gconf
.gnome2
.gstreamer-0.10
.gtk-bookmarks
.gvfs
Hacking
.icons
.idlerc
indiecity
.local
.Mathematica
.minecraft
.noip
.pki
.profile
.pulse
.pulse-cookie
.python_games
Scripts
.sonic-pi
.ssh
.thumbnails
.vnc
weaved-nixinstaller_1.2.13.bin
weaved_software
.WolframEngine
.Xauthority
.xsession-errors
.xsession-errors.old
```

#### Update 1

Unfortunately, I tried making my own `~/.xinitrc` with `exec mate-session` in it(in the SSH), and ran `startx` and my Pi began spitting out errors(at least I think they are errors), and nothing happened... I rebooted, (`sudo reboot`), and ran `startx` *in the VNC*, and the terminal began spitting out errors and then nothing happened... I am not sure if it is an error with the VNC not displaying, or something else, but I would greatly appreciate any answers.

#### Update 2

Here are the errors recieved from running `startx` via SSH:

```
hostname: Name or service not known
xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "raspberrypi:3" in "add" command


X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-2-mx5 armv7l Debian
Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l
Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=592 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=448 bcm2708.boardrev=0xe bcm2708.serial=0x44102c8a smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:10:2C:8A bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
Build Date: 11 February 2015  09:31:17PM
xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u6 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.1
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.3.log", Time: Wed Jun 10 21:16:56 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
FATAL: Module g2d_23 not found.
mate-session[3907]: WARNING: Unable to determine session: Unable to lookup session information for process '3907'
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-ANl7aF
MATE_KEYRING_PID=3920
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-ANl7aF
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-ANl7aF
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-ANl7aF/gpg:0:1
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-ANl7aF
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-ANl7aF/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-ANl7aF/ssh
[1433971022,000,xklavier.c:xkl_engine_start_listen/]    The backend does not require manual layout management    but it is provided by the application

(mate-panel:3935): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3935): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-bar-popup-delay after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3935): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3935): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popup-delay after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3935): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3935): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-images after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3935): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
mate-session[3907]: WARNING: Could not launch application 'gnome-do.desktop': Unable to start application: Failed to execute child process "gnome-do" (No such file or directory)

(polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1:3984): polkit-mate-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '3984'

** (lxpolkit:3988): CRITICAL **: polkit_agent_listener_register_with_options: assertion 'POLKIT_IS_SUBJECT (subject)' failed

(lxpolkit:3988): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised

** (mate-power-backlight-helper:4037): WARNING **: failed to find any devices: Error opening directory '/sys/class/backlight': No such file or directory

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-bar-popup-delay after class was initialised

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popup-delay after class was initialised

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-images after class was initialised

** (mate-power-manager:3989): WARNING **: levels is 0!

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised

** (caja:3974): WARNING **: Failed to get the current CK session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '3974'

(caja:3974): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-scrolled-window-placement after class was initialised
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-2-mx5 armv7l Debian
Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l
Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=592 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=448 bcm2708.boardrev=0xe bcm2708.serial=0x44102c8a smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:10:2C:8A bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
Build Date: 11 February 2015  09:31:17PM
xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u6 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.1
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.3.log", Time: Wed Jun 10 21:15:24 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
FATAL: Module g2d_23 not found.
mate-session[3733]: WARNING: Unable to determine session: Unable to lookup session information for process '3733'
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-gAczeJ
MATE_KEYRING_PID=3746
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-gAczeJ
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-gAczeJ
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-gAczeJ/gpg:0:1
MATE_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-gAczeJ
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-gAczeJ/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-gAczeJ/ssh

(mate-panel:3761): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised
[1433970930,000,xklavier.c:xkl_engine_start_listen/]    The backend does not require manual layout management    but it is provided by the application

(mate-panel:3761): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-bar-popup-delay after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3761): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3761): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popup-delay after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3761): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3761): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-images after class was initialised

(mate-panel:3761): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
mate-session[3733]: WARNING: Could not launch application 'gnome-do.desktop': Unable to start application: Failed to execute child process "gnome-do" (No such file or directory)

(polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1:3800): polkit-mate-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '3800'

** (lxpolkit:3804): CRITICAL **: polkit_agent_listener_register_with_options: assertion 'POLKIT_IS_SUBJECT (subject)' failed

(lxpolkit:3804): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(caja:3790): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
Failure: Module initialization failed

** (mate-power-backlight-helper:3853): WARNING **: failed to find any devices: Error opening directory '/sys/class/backlight': No such file or directory

(caja:3790): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-bar-popup-delay after class was initialised

(caja:3790): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised

** (mate-power-manager:3805): WARNING **: levels is 0!

(caja:3790): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
```

Comment: That's totally normal.  It doesn't need to exist, so unless there's a reason for it, it won't.  As per PythonNut's answer, you can just create one.

Comment: @Interesting... could you, perhaps, paste the errors here?

Comment: Yes... I will put it in an *update*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Create a blank `~/.xinitrc` and continue your work
2. Edit `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` instead

Comment: #1 is probably preferable.  I am pretty sure what PythonNut means here by "continue your work" is to then edit the new, blank `.xinitrc` and put the `exec` command in there.

Comment: Thanks... I am trying it rights as we speak, but my main worry is that I do not have a hard connection to my pi, and therefore have to SSH to VNC... I am worried that might cause problems...